# WebLogic server automatically registered JAX-RS/Jersey REST JBoss BPM to wrong URL

Tags: java, jboss, weblogic12c, jboss6.x, business-process-management

I have WebLogic Server Version: 12.2.1.2.0 and JBoss BPM Suite version 6.4.0.
I try deploy business-central.war application to WebLogic Server.
Defoult business-central.war have web.xml where use this servlet:

```
    <!-- REST servlets -->
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
      <!-- REST Permissions -->
      <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

From [doc WebLogic](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/RESTF/deploy-restful-service.htm#RESTF191) I see, that business-central.war build correctly, but after deploy to server, url changes to /resources/*, and WebLogic write [ **/resources/*** ] (automatically registered) JAX-RS/Jersey#1
I have two important questions:

1. Why WebLogic automatically registered on [default URL](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/RESTF/deploy-restful-service.htm#RESTF191) (end page).
2. What to do for correctly URL to **/rest/***

Thank.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow this doc:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/RESTF/deploy-restful-service.htm#RESTF319

The doc you offered is wls 1213. But you use weblogic 12.2.1

Comment: Thanks, but I read this doc and business-central.war hold right settings.

Comment: Do you want to use jersey 1.x server side api on wls 12.2.1?

Comment: I want use business-central.war for WebLogic on server WebLogic. I dont'n know wich version Jersey used in business-central.war, but I use .war special for WebLogic and very surprised, that this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to Jersey 2.x jar files, use org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer as servlet-class in web.xml and retry.